# Lightning Record Page Related List - Single configuration

Tags: flexipages, lightning-record-page

On two different Lightning Record Pages I'm displaying a Related List - Single component for Notes. The client likes the view when Related List Type is Enhanced List. This shows a table version of the Notes list and works when the column the component is dropped in is at least 2/3 of the page. When the component is dropped into a column 1/3 size of the page, it reverts to the Basic List view.
Two questions:
Is there a way to make it stay in Enhanced List view (table format)?
Can I control the columns that are displayed in the Enhanced List view?